# convert string to an integer?

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, integer, cpu-word

My console shows me:

```
For input string: "zero"
For input string: "one"
```

My runs shows me:

```
runs: 4/4 error:3 failures: 1
```

This is one of my 4 assignments, I'm new to Java and I would like if someone could help me out with this. I don't know how to convert words into integers and I'm also not sure if the rest of my code is right.

Comment: Hello. Please don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when it comes to text, you are only looking for the first 10 numbers. zero, one, two and so on. You could go for something like this though this is not very scalable when it comes to more numbers in string format, should be fine for your example.

At the switch statement you are trying to see if there is a valid text match to a number. If there is, return that. You will not reach the try/catch.

Otherwise carry on to the try/catch part and try to format the value to a number. If valid, return it. Else catch the error and return 0;

It will throw an error if for example the text value is "some random text".

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(getNum("1"));
        System.out.println(getNum("two"));
    }

    private static int getNum(String num) {
        switch (num) {
            case "zero" : return 0;
            case "one" : return 1;
            case "two" : return 2;
            // carry on to add the case for the remaining 7 numbers
        }

        try {
            return Integer.parseInt(num);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store "zero" to "nine" in a `List<String>` in the order of counting and return the corresponding index. If a string does not exist in the list, assign `0` to the return value.

First, try to convert the input into `int` using [`Integer#parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) and if it fails, look for the string in the list.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String[] arr = { "five", "two", "abc", "nine", "123", "0", "-20", "xyz" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + convertStringToInt(s));
        }
    }

    static int convertStringToInt(String numberString) {
        List<String> list = List.of("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine");
        int retVal = 0, index = 0;
        try {
            retVal = Integer.parseInt(numberString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            index = list.indexOf(numberString.toLowerCase());
            retVal = index == -1 ? 0 : index;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
five => 5
two => 2
abc => 0
nine => 9
123 => 123
0 => 0
-20 => -20
xyz => 0
```

Answer (score -1):

An manual if (...) else (...) is the only way (without an external Library) I think, thats because of languages